# mysql select distinct - show value and totals

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue as I am still very new to mysql, so here is what I am trying to do. I have a table which contains user1 user2 and a number

Example:

```
user1 user2 1
user5 user17 1
user44 user33 12
user1 user5 1
user1 user24 1
user5 user666 1
```

What I am trying to do is listing the first user field first and then then the amount of user2 values sorted by that amount.

For the example above, I would like the results to look like:

```
user1 3
user5 2
user44 1
```

Reason being that user1 is in the user1 field three times, user 5 two times and user 44 one time. It's basically a referral system I have coded and now I would like to show who referred most users to my site. user1 is the referrer and user2 the referred.

I would also like to list a maximum amount of 10 rows as in LIMIT 10

Any suggestions how I would do this query and output it with php? I know how to do the connection part to mysql - I just don't know how exactly to echo this the way I want to.

Thank you for your help in this matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
select user1, count(*) Total
from yourtable 
group by user1
order by total desc
limit 0, 10
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b412/7)

*Note: your column names were not clear from your description*

Comment: Would you know how to access the total number via PHP? I have while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getuid)){
echo $row['user1'];?>
} and cannot find out how to echo the total number

Comment: @MarcusWeller I am not familiar with php but [this link](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm) appears to have some details

Comment: @MarcusWeller: `var_dump($row);` - will tell you what you get back and how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem.

```
select user1, count(*) as Total
from tablename
group by user1
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it please ?

```
SELECT username,count(username)
FROM yourtablename
Group By username
Order by 2 desc
```